# Multiline mode search and replace in perl

Tags: regex, perl, powershell

Given the following type of input (contained within numerous files):

```
ret = myFunc(&pConfig->hConstraintList, &pConfig->util,
                   2, sizeof(rcConstraint_t),
                   NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I'm trying to get the following regex to match:

```
myFunc\((\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*?),\s*NULL,\s*NULL,\s*NULL,\s*NULL\s*\).*;
```

The idea is to replace this with the following:

```
myFuncNoCB($1 $2 $3 $4 $5);
```

This works as a .NET regex, but doing in-file search and replace in powershell is a pain, and the VS UI doesn't fully support multiline expressions.

So...perl.  But I can't even get the match to work:

Here's what I've tried:

```
perl -0ne '/myFunc\((\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*?),\s*NULL,\s*NULL,\s*NULL,\s*NULL\s*\).*;/gms' myfile.cpp
```

My assumption is that perl doesn't consider a newline whitespace even in multiline mode?  That's going to be a complete nightmare as each parameter could have any number of spaces, tabs, newlines, in any order between them.

I'm interested in any solution that works, to be frank.  There's a lot of variables here.  I did a `perl -pi -e 's/\r//g'` on this particular file to eliminate that potential issue but I would love a solution that doesn't choke on `\r` as well.

PS--I've google searched this question, and searched on stackoverflow.  The issue is that most people that use "multiline" just need to search multiple lines...one at a time.  Those that use it correctly have significantly different patterns they are trying to match that don't help me.  If there's an answer that helps me, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `/m` modifier, as it changes the behaviour of `^` and `$` none of which you use in the regex.

The same applies to `/s` - it makes `.` match a newline, but you don't need it, `\s` already matches all whitespace including newlines.

I'd list commas in the regex and omit the `.*` at the end as it could (with `/s`) match the rest of the document.

```
perl -0pe 's/myFunc\((\S*),\s*(\S*),\s*(\S*),\s*(\S*),\s*(\S*?),
             \s*NULL,\s*NULL,\s*NULL,\s*NULL\s*\)
            /myFuncNoCB($1, $2, $3, $4)/xg' -- file
```

Comment: This looks great, and I appreciate the clarifications on things I could be doing better. Did you see anything that would’ve been causing my regex not to match?

Comment: We'd need more examples of what you want to match (or what you don't want to match) to be of more help.

Comment: @zzxyx:  The non-space fields should probably be `\S+` as it doesn't make sense for all of those to match nothing

Comment: The issue that your regex fixed was that I did not want `;` in my regex as the usage in the test was `if(myFunc(etc)){`  So... the *primary issue* was basically a bug rather than a misunderstanding of some fundamental.  I know stackoverflow is big on questions that can help other people.  Should I delete it?

Comment: I see no reason to delete it, especially if the answer helped you. I can update the answer to explicitly mention the semicolon if it makes you feel better?

Comment: @choroba - nah, I would have to update my question as well :)